# Git - fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD' & notice: HEAD points to unborn branch (master)

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am a newbie to all this and currently taking a class to learn git.  However, I was in the process of practicing branching and merging.  I had created a new branch and it was switched but my computer started to have issues, which cause me to shut it down and restart.  When I return to my work, I returned to this:

```
>git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what

        .gitconfig
        AppData/
        Contacts/
        Creative Cloud Files/
        Desktop/
        Documents/
        Downloads/
        Favorites/
        Links/
        Music/
        NTUSER.DAT{9f037fb3-2982-11e3-93f1-b8c
        NTUSER.DAT{9f037fb3-2982-11e3-93f1-b8c00000001.regtrans-ms
        NTUSER.DAT{9f037fb3-2982-11e3-93f1-b8c00000002.regtrans-ms
        ntuser.dat{290469cc-4e2a-11e3-bebb-68500000002.regtrans-ms
```

I have no idea of what ntuser.dat means and when I run git fsck my return looks like this:

notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
notice: No default references

When I doing git log, I receive the fatal bad error.  I have tried to reset and nothing seems to be working.  Can someone please provide me with assistance?

Additionally, I am using a PC, which requires me to use the command prompt for Windows.

Comment: Did you run a `git init` in `C:\Users\Sandy` before the crash?  Your whole user directory was under Git version control?  Also, did you make any commits before the crash?

Comment: Yes, I ran a git init and did one commit before the crash.  The git init was done on a file located on my c: drive but I notice that my whole directory is under Git version control.  Is there any way to change that?  I am totally not interested in that.

Comment: You can't run `git init` on "a file", it has to be done inside a directory or on a directory.

Comment: I just tried the git symbolic from the article you provided but nothing happened.

Comment: I have only used git init and commit  to create my repository.  After that, I started to practice with branching and merging when I incurred computer issues.

Comment: Now that I thought about it, the answer I linked as a possible duplicate doesn't match your problem. Go with what I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this happened...

1. You ran `git init` in `C:\Users\Sandy`.
2. You may have done other things.
3. Your computer crashed.
4. You rebooted.
5. Whatever you did in #2 was lost.

What you're seeing right now is a Git repository with no commits and a master branch that points to nothing.  That's normal after you've created a repository.  Here, I can recreate it right now.

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/schwern/tmp/foo/.git/
$ git log
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)

$ git fsck
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
notice: No default references
```

All you need to do to fix this is `git add` and `git commit` something and proceed as normal.

As for why you're seeing all that junk in `git status`, Git repositories cover a directory and all subdirectories.  If you ran `git init` in `C:\Users\Sandy` then the repository will try to track everything in your home directory and all subdirectories.  [NTUSER.dat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_profiles_in_Microsoft_Windows#Profile_contents) is normal Windows administrative files that Windows normally hides from you.  Git doesn't care what a file is and shows you everything.

You probably don't want to put your entire home directory in version control.  Not that it would hurt anything, it's just not practical.  Instead, do as I did and create a new directory and run `git init` there.

As for your repository in the home directory, just delete it.  A Git repository is stored in a `.git` sub-directory immediately inside your project directory.  Delete `C:\Users\Sandy\.git\` and you're done.  In my example above, it would be `foo/.git/`.

PS  You can't run `git init` on a file, it has to be in a directory.

Comment: Forgive me for all the questions, I am only working with the command prompt at this moment, so I not aware of any project directory.  Also, I have tried git add and git commit and it does not work. The folder that I was working with on my c: drive is no longer there; however, my files are still on Notepad++.  I am trying to understand but this is getting so frustrating.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: I encourage you to continue to work with the command prompt!  At this point, GUIs will just interfere with your understanding of Git.  By "project directory" I should have said "working directory" which means whatever is under version control (in your case, `C:\Users\Sandy` and in my case `foo/`).  At this point I would suggest you just delete the `.git` directory and start over, it seems to be confusing you.  Whatever you did before the crash is likely gone.

Comment: Yayyyyy, deleting the .git directory did the trick.  Thank you, thank you so much for your patience and knowledge.  Boy, that was a great learning experience.  I am truly gratitude for all you assistance.  Starting over will be a breeze since I was just getting started.  Oh yea, I also deleted the .git config file.  Let me know if that was alright.