# Undo git reset --hard with bad revision 'HEAD'

Tags: git

I was trying to upload my project to bitbucket and was experiencing issues. I kept receiving the error "bad default revision 'HEAD'" while trying to push my project.

To make a long story short I stupidly typed "git reset --hard" into my terminal clearing my entire project. I'm terrified that I just lost an insane amount of work. I've been trying to undo the command with commands like "git reflog" and "git reset HEAD@{1}" but I keep receiving the error "fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'".

Is there some way to undo this? I have been working on this project for over a month now and to lose this much progress would be devastating.

**EDIT:**
I tried to use "git reflog" again and it still returned the following error:
[image]

When I run "git fsck", however, it prints the following:
[image]

The dangling blobs are the files that I am missing, I ran git show on one of them and it appeared to be one of the 256 files I was looking for.

Comment: Find the last commit you were on in the reflog, check it out and then create a branch from it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated my question

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305654/git-fatal-bad-default-revision-head-notice-head-points-to-unborn-branch) explains the unborn branch error.